# Rails merge tags

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I need to insert a merge-tag in a text. For example I have the merge tag |NAME|, so, I would like to replace |NAME| in any part of a paragraph. For example if |NAME| = Carlos

Lorep ipsum |NAME| dorel pored = Lorep ipsum Carlos dorel pored

or

|NAME| Lorep ipsum dorel pored = Carlos Lorep ipsum  dorel pored

How can I do that with rails?
Are there some plugin in rails for that?
Thanks in advance

---

### UPDATE

Sorry, I think I explained bad. This not have to be hard coded. The user has a textbox where he can decide where to put the merge-tag to appear in any place of the text entered.

Answer (score 0):

in **controller**:

```
@name = 'Carlos'
```

in **view**:

```
Lorep ipsum <%= @name %> dorel pored
```